How to use New Computer Modern Book?
I would like to use the "book" weight of this version of the font New Computer Modern (https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern?lang=en) to get a slightly "blacker" type with Typst.
In LaTeX (using xelatex), it can be loaded via \usepackage[default]{fontsetup}. For Typst, I downloaded and installed the .otf files on MacOS using homebrew. However, only the "08" (point?) version of the font works; the "10" (point) one does not: warning: unknown font family: newcomputermodern10
Apparently, New Computer Modern 08 comes without a boldface so some of my formatting is lost:
#set text(font: "New Computer Modern 08")

= Heading
The heading should be *bold*. 


Any way to make this work? I can't see why one should work while the other does not judging by the Font Book entries:


Typst provides the New Computer Modern 10 (Regular, Bold, and Italic) with its binary in the name of New Computer Modern. Thus, before installing font-new-computer-modern, you can get these variants:
> typst fonts --variants | rg Computer -A 10
New Computer Modern
- Style: Normal, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 700, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 700, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
New Computer Modern Math
- Style: Normal, Weight: 700, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 450, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
...

After installing font-new-computer-modern, more variants will be shown:
> brew install font-new-computer-modern
...
> typst fonts --variants | rg Computer -A 10
New Computer Modern
- Style: Normal, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 700, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 450, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 450, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 700, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 700, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 700, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
New Computer Modern 08
- Style: Normal, Weight: 450, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Italic, Weight: 450, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
...

Notice that the normal style font has three weights: 400, 450, and 700. The font book also shows there are three font files:
$HOME/Library/Fonts/NewCM10-Bold.otf
$HOME/Library/Fonts/NewCM10-Book.otf
$HOME/Library/Fonts/NewCM10-Regular.otf

I assume the new 450 weight variant is the book weight variant, and here is a simple example:
#set page(margin: 1em)

#let test_text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

#text(font: "New Computer Modern", weight: 400)[#test_text]

#text(font: "New Computer Modern", weight: 450)[#test_text]

#text(font: "New Computer Modern", weight: 700)[#test_text]

#text(font: "New Computer Modern", weight: "regular")[#test_text]

#text(font: "New Computer Modern", weight: "medium")[#test_text]

#text(font: "New Computer Modern", weight: "bold")[#test_text]


Notice:

I haven't checked the metadata of the OTF file to see if Book has a weight of 450.
The weight: "medium" sets the weight to 500, and I think typst uses the nearest weight and gets the 450.

I hope this solves your problem.

Learned a lot here... Any chance you might have insight on this related problem too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79249081/system-font-not-available-with-typst
