System font not available with Typst
I would like to access different weights of the font STIX Two Text using Typst. According to Font Book, MacOS comes with different weights of the font pre-installed:

However, typst fonts --variants | rg STIX -A 10 only lists a single weight:
STIX Two Text
- Style: Italic, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)
- Style: Normal, Weight: 400, Stretch: FontStretch(1000)

How can I make the other weights available to Typst? I tried re-installing the font from an online source after which bold became available (but not semibold), not to speak of the mess of having the same font installed twice side-by-side.

It seems that the pre-installed fonts are variable-width ones which Typst does not currently support: https://github.com/typst/typst/issues/185

I think you can download the variant from STIX's GitHub repo and use typst compile --font-path /path/to/fonts to compile your code. The repo is at https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/tree/master/fonts/static_otf

Thanks! I was able to install the static font versions next to the variable width system fonts and have Typst access them
